# VLOOKUP is not working is not working and I don't know why

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

VLOOKUP is not working and I dont't know why and I'm going crazy. Any help appreciated.

**Goal:**

I have a list with names and [postcodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dM63x.png) and I want to match them with a second [sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3MBr.png) which has the same postcodes but more information about the place!

**My Solution:**

```
=VLOOKUP("" & B2 & "",'Targeting Google Ads'!A:B,2,FALSE)
```

The problem is, as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjIMq.png), it says it did not find the value "1010", when it's clearly there.

Is it a problem that the value I want to get in return is formated like that?

```
Innere Stadt,Vienna,Austria
```

Funny thing is, the exact same principle work [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60CBu.png) and I'm using:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,'Alle PLZ in AT'!A:B,2,0),"")
```

Don't know if that's allowed, but [here's](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dEpzgbIL_BECE-AZaCDQ64GYlnRgLsRfxwI-hew3wYA/edit?usp=sharing) the actual sheet to check

I really tried, but now it's just pissing me off that my skills are so mediocre, so any help highly appreciated!

Thank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a formatting issue. The values in 'PLZ AT Tabelle' are text, the values in 'Targeting Google Ads' are numbers.

So you should either force the formatting of the second sheet to Plain Text or the formatting of the first sheet to Numbers and remove the concatenations in your VLOOKUP search_key.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=vlookup(to_text(B2),'Alle PLZ in AT'!A:B,2,0)
```